# How to make a global variable that uses "self" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, global-variables

Hello Im currently using swift in xCode and I have a random number generator that produces a random point in the view.

```
        func randomInRange(lo: Int, hi : Int) -> Int {
            return lo + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(hi - lo + 1)))
        }
        // x coordinate between MinX (left) and MaxX (right):
        let randomX = randomInRange(Int(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) * 2), Int(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)))
        // y coordinate between MinY (top) and MidY (bottom):
        let randomY = randomInRange(Int(CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) * 2), Int(CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)))
        let randomPoint = CGPoint(x: randomX , y: randomY)
```

I would like to global use this variable so i can use this random point multiple times rather then have to write out this entire code block every time. Now I know you can create a global variable by declaring it above the GameScene class or in-between the class and the viewDidLoad like such

```
class GameScene: SKScene , SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


func randomInRange(lo: Int, hi : Int) -> Int {
    return lo + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(hi - lo + 1)))
}
// x coordinate between MinX (left) and MaxX (right):
let randomX = randomInRange(Int(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) * 2), Int(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)))
// y coordinate between MinY (top) and MidY (bottom):
let randomY = randomInRange(Int(CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) * 2), Int(CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)))
let randomPoint = CGPoint(x: randomX , y: randomY)


 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
```

However when I put it above the same scene class I get the error message... 
"Use of unresolved identifier self"
And when i put it between the gameScene class and viewDidLoad I get the error ...
gameScene does not have a member named self .
If possible is there a way to replace self with something else regarding the view , If so please answer. 
Thank you !

Comment: Use a singleton class to share it.

Comment: do you want to use this one time only computed property as global const or have possibilty to compute it many times in different controllers/views?

Comment: Im not entirely sure how a to use / create singleton classes, How can I implement my random point in one? also where is the class to be placed? thanks Thomas

Comment: I only want it in one controller and one view. And as a global variable @Kubba

Comment: global variables are not a good idea, think twice before using them. If you want to calculate your property only once, in this particular controller and use in multiple places later you can in example:

(1) store it i this controller and the pass it around
(2) store it in some singleton (If don't have one, use AppDelegate)
(3) save it in NSUserDefaults

Comment: I agree with @Kubba - there is no need for a global or a singleton here.  Simply compute the value in `didMoveToView` (although I suspect you will find that the frame values aren't correct at this point) and store it in a property of your view controller.  You can then access `self.randomPoint` anywhere in this class.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your global function above the GameScene class and replace `self.frame` with `UIScreen.main.bounds`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a singleton like this:

```
class MyGlobalCounters {
  var counter = 0
  var this = "Hello"
  var that:CGFloat = 1.23

  class var sharedInstance : MyGlobalCounters {
    return _SingletonSharedInstance
  }
}
private let _SingletonSharedInstance = MyGlobalCounters()


class A {
  let myGlobalCounters = MyGlobalCounters.sharedInstance
  func dumpAndInc() {
    println("ctr=\(myGlobalCounters.counter++)")
  }
}

class B {
  let myGlobalCounters = MyGlobalCounters.sharedInstance
  func dumpAndInc() {
    println("ctr=\(myGlobalCounters.counter++)")
  }
}
let a = A()
let b = B()
a.dumpAndInc() 
b.dumpAndInc() // in b we use the same instance for the counters
a.dumpAndInc() // as in a
```